# How to write generic Entity name in constructor in EF4?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, generics

i try to write Generic Repository in EF 4. But my codes is not looking good. Because ExpressionEntities is not GENERIC.

I want to convert this codes:

```
public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ExpressionsEntities _context;
    public DataRepository()
    {
    }

    public DataRepository(ExpressionsEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

to the following:

```
public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private GetGenericEntityCONTEXT _context;

    public DataRepository()
    {
    }

    public DataRepository(GetGenericEntityCONTEXT  context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

because ExpressionsEntities  not global my entities : ExpressionsEntities1, ExpressionsEntities 2, ExpressionsEntities 3 etx... i need to write get take entity for example:

```
public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private Entity _context;
    public DataRepository()
    {
    }

    public DataRepository(Entity context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public class Main
    {
        main()
        {
            new DataRepository(ExpressionEntities)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your asking - from what i can understand, you wan't a way to *dynamically* create the entity set based on T.

Well that's easy enough:

```
public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private ObjectContext _ctx; 

   public DataRepository<T>(ObjectContext ctx)
   {
      this._ctx = ctx;
   }

   public IObjectSet<T> CurrentEntitySet<T>()
   {
       get
       {
          var entityName = _plularizer.Pluralize(typeof(T).Name);
          string entitySetName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", EntityContainerName, entityName);
          return _ctx.CreateObjectSet<T>(entitySetName );  
       }
   }
}
```

Then your **specific** Repository could do this (for example):

```
public class AppleRepository : DataRepository<Apple>
{
   public AppleRepository(IObjectContext ctx) : base(ctx) {}

   public ICollection<Apple> FindApples(Func<Apple,bool> predicate)
   {
      return CurrentEntitySet.Where(predicate).ToList();
   }
}
```

And when your creating your repository, pass through the object context - preferably by DI:

```
var repository = new AppleRepository(new ExpressionEntities()); // should be DI'ed
```

Basically, we're making use of **Pluralization** (the same code used by Entity Framework to pluralize entity set names), and **`CreateObjectSet<T>`**.

So if you created a **`DataRepository<Apple>`**, that would translate to an entity set name of **Apples** (which should match the entity set on your model), and we create an entity set based on that.

The **EntityContainerName** property is what's on your EDMX - you should pass this through the ctor (via DI preferably).

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Loo please above codes: My codes generic but ExpressionsEntities  not generic according to above codes i should write every entities.

Comment: @Phsika - what is "ExpressionEntities" - is that your data context? I'll take a guess and say yes, and update my answer.

Comment: And no, you don't need a repository per entity. You should have a repository *per aggregate root*. Create an interface for each aggregate root, and inject either the DataRepository<T> or a specific repository (which derives from the DataRepository<T> and thus satisfies the interface contract). The whole point of the generic repository is to reduce the number of implementations.

Comment: Thanks:) ExpressionsEntities is my datacontext

Comment: wait me 5 minutes i will ;) Thanks again you are great but i want to use it now...

Comment: private IObjectContext _ctx;  is not defined. I opened Model. Designer.cs i implement     public interface IObjectContext 
{
BUT NOT WORKING :(
}
    public partial class ExpressionsEntities : ObjectContext , IObjectContext

Comment: What do you mean "not defined"? When you instantiate your repository (like i showed in my answer), you pass through ExpressionEntities which implements IObjectContext. Are you getting a compile-time/runtime error? You don't need to touch your designer.cs file.

Comment: if i implement IObjectContext : http://i56.tinypic.com/20qb42x.png . i can not use IObjectContext

Comment: @Phsika - sorry, i got confused with IObjectSet<T>. There is no IObjectContext. Change it to ObjectContext (see my edit). And please tick this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Phsika - it is highly inpolite to not tick this as the correct answer, after all the effort i put into helping you. If you don't start choosing correct answers, people (myself included) will stop helping you.

Comment: Sorry RPM1984; i am really bussy. Your answer has opened my horizons. Your answer is correct. Sorry because of the delay...

Comment: @Phsika - no problems, at least you came back and addressed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to get the entityName like this.

`EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);`

`EntitySetBase entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets.Where(item => item.ElementType.Name.Equals(typeof(T).Name)).FirstOrDefault();`

`var entityName = entitySet.Name`

This deals with some cases if you have some classes pluralized, and some classes not.